# Python crashes with 2 worker threads in PyQt5 application

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, pyqt5

I would like to have 2 worker threads in my application. One should start running as soon as the GUI is loaded and another one should start later by some signal. Let's say it's a button click.

I came across a weird behavior when my Python interpreter crashes(as in shows me Windows error "Python stopped working", no stack trace) on executing the second thread.

Here is an example, that will crash right after I click the button.

```
class Worker(QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self, method_to_run):
        super().__init__()
        self.method = method_to_run

    def run(self):
        self.method()

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.button = QPushButton('Test', self)
        self.label = QLabel(self)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.handleButton)
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.label)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.worker = Worker(self.test_method)
        self.worker.start()

    def handleButton(self):
        self.label.setText('Button Clicked!')
        worker = Worker(self.test_method)
        worker.start() 

    @staticmethod
    def test_method():
        res = [i*i for i in range(100500)]

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

What's more weird is that it doesn't crash when you debug the application for some reason.

What am I missing here?

**Edit**
I could get much from the crashdump, as I don't have symbols for QT. But it looks like the crash happens inside QtCore.dll

```
ExceptionAddress: 00000000632d4669 (Qt5Core!QThread::start+0x0000000000000229)
```

Comment: Can you include the stack trace?

Comment: well, my python interpreter crashes with a Windows error "Python.exe stopped working" I will try to analyze the crash dump, but it's not going to be helpful as I don't have debug symbols. There is no Python stack trace as the interpreter crashes itself...

Comment: Side-note: If this is pure Py3 code, you can use no-arg `super` for simplicity. `super(Window, self).__init__()` is only needed in Py2, in Py3, `super().__init__()` is cleaner, faster, and behaves the same (unless you do something terrible like reassign `Window` at global scope after defining it).

Comment: thanks, fixed that too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you didn't save a reference to the thread so it was deleted as soon as you exited `handleButton`. If you save a reference, that begs the question of how to handle its lifespan.

`QThread` is more than just a wrapper to a system thread - it implements other services that let you wire a thread into your GUI. You can use its `finished` handler to signal the widget when it terminates to do any cleanup.

In this example, I save the worker as `self.worker2` and block starting the worker a second time until the first one completes.

```
import PyQt5
import PyQt5.QtCore as QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import time

class Worker(QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self, method_to_run):
        super(Worker, self).__init__()
        self.method = method_to_run

    def run(self):
        self.method()

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.button = QPushButton('Test', self)
        self.label = QLabel(self)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.handleButton)
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.label)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.worker = Worker(self.test_method)
        self.worker.start()
        self.worker2 = None

    def handleButton(self):
        self.label.setText('Button Clicked!')
        # likely better to disable the button instead... but
        # this shows events in action.
        if self.worker2:
            self.label.setText('Worker already running')
        else:
            self.worker2 = Worker(self.test_method)
            self.worker2.finished.connect(self.handle_worker2_done)
            self.worker2.start() 

    def handle_worker2_done(self):
        self.worker2 = None
        self.label.setText('Worker done')

    @staticmethod
    def test_method():
        #res = [i*i for i in range(100500)]
        time.sleep(3)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1):

Your click triggered thread isn't actually trying to do work in a thread. You *called* the method, rather than passing the method as an argument, so you're trying to use the return value of `test_method` (`None`) as the method to run.

Change:

```
worker = Worker(self.test_method())  # Calls test_method and tries to run None
```

to:

```
worker = Worker(self.test_method)  # Don't call test_method
```

Comment: sorry, it's a copy-paste bug :) obviously it isn't there and still crashes.